# Exporting a webpage containing VueJS to a locally stored HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Usecase: I want to allow users to download a static export of a webpage containing VueJS as a Javascript framework.

I've tried to export using filesaver.js and blob with mimetype `text/html`, replacing relative paths to the original host so that these payloads are delivered by the webserver:

```js
let host = window.location.origin
let html_string = document.documentElement.outerHTML
html_string = html_string.replace(/\/build\//g, host+'/build/')
var fileblob = new Blob([html_string], { type: 'text/html' })
this.filesaver.saveAs(fileblob, this.title+".html");
```

However, the result is a page with correct styling and application javascript, but without any interaction.
VueJS is not detected by the debugger, but the window does have a `window.vm` containing the Vue instance.

The same behavior occurs when I try to save the file through the browser as self contained html file (`.mhtml` extension). Webpage looks proper with all styling and scripts included, but there's no actual javscript being executed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, posting for posterity:
The problem was that the components in the file were already replaced by their VueJS templates in the original html, and therefore not being mounted in the downloaded static file.

The solution was to generate the HTML in the backend (in this case with a Laravel `render()`) function, and stream that into a file for the user. This file then does contain the correct components, which are in turn substituted by the VueJS javscript.